# Render only template wrapper Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView

Tags: backbone.js, render, marionette

I have a template with header (select filters) and section with list of models of collection. The view (Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView) always renders automatically on the first load both template wrapper and models.

Is there any way to render only template wrapper on the first load?

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can switch templates on the fly.

```
initialize: function(){
    this.template = template1(); // initial render will use template 1
},
onRender: function(){
    this.template = template2(); // point to template 2 after every render. So each subsequesnt render will use template 2.
},
doStuff: function(){
    this.render(); // call render when doing stuff
}
```

Comment: It doesnt help. It just renders those models in different place.

Comment: Well, without you providing some code it's kinda hard to help. I'd like to know what you've tried.